# How to make MockServer not respond?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockserver

I want to use java `MockServer` only to catch the requests made to some endpoint and not to respond (it's vital to test my retry settings in `Spring`). Does anyone know if it's possible?

Comment: But don't you retry based on specific (HTTP Status Code, for example 429 )? Why can't you mock those responses with this HttpStatus code.  Please clarify If I misunderstood your requirements.

Comment: @SMA Well, actually I can't modify these retry settings, as they're the Google API settings and the request is being made not by me directly. These settings are being applied only if a server is not responding...

Comment: Do you mean you are calling a specific API and you timeout after a while without any HTTP response/status code? Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @SMA No, when the server is not responding I am retrying my calls with a specific pattern applied. i want to test this pattern and that's why I need a proxy to intercept those calls..